# Ignore react-router route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

There's a component on '/example' route. When I navigate to that path, the  component being rendered. The problem is that I need to ignore rendering  component and get redirected to the external link (which happen to have the same route) - '/example'. Is there any way for me to ignore or get around react-router route?

Comment: use a `<a ...></a>` instead of `<Link>`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a one-liner for using React Router to redirect to an external link:

```
<Route path='/privacy-policy' component={() => { 
     window.location.href = 'https://example.com/1234'; 
     return null;
}}/>
```

Comment: Using React, and implementing multiple sso providers configured via Spring Security 5, This was a working solution i could find to get around reactRouter and hit my backend oauth2 endpoints. thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Redirect

```
<Route path="/example" render={() => {
   return <Redirect  to="//external.url/example" />
}} />
```

Or if you have a `<Switch>` around the routes you can shorten it:

```
<Redirect from="/example" to="//external.url/example" />
```