# Github page URL routes to homepage when deployed (works fine when run locally)

Tags: reactjs, github, url, deployment, github-pages

I have a react-app portfolio that is deployed using github pages:
https://briandgomez.github.io/cp-retrofolio/

When I click on this icon for this specific project only:
[Projects Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU13l.png)
It displays the homepage but with this URL which is incorrect:
[Portfolio WebPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu3Vt.png)

I would like the proper webpage to be opened when the icon is clicked which  looks like this:
[YER WebPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYzd7.jpg)

I believe that this is happening because the link that is embedded in the icon is from a different react-app I created that is also deployed using github pages and github pages does not understand it is a different app.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Is there a easy fix solution to this or will I have to deploy my portfolio another way?

Thanks in advance

**Note**:

1. This issue is only occurring for this specific project (Y.E.R) and when deployed. It works fine locally.
2. Here is the link to the react-app that is embedded in my portfolio:
   https://github.com/briandgomez/YER

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore react-router route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572051/ignore-react-router-route)

Answer (score 0):

Since the link has the same host as the website (`https://briandgomez.github.io/`), React Router assumes that it should handle the request. Since there is no explicit `<Route>` for it in the app, React Router shows the index page.

To work around this, you could consider using a [loader](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader) that invokes a [document redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirectDocument):

> This is most useful when you have a React Router app living next to a separate app on the same domain and need to redirect from the React Router app to the other app via `window.location` instead of a React Router navigation